# Why we should pass watchify arguments to browserify?

Tags: browserify, watchify

From the document of [watchify](https://github.com/substack/watchify), I see:

> When creating the browserify instance b you MUST set these properties in the constructor:
>
> ```
> var b = browserify({ cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true })
> ```

The 3 parameters `cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true` are for watchify, but why we should pass them to `browserify` instead of passing to `watchify`?

Answer (score 2):

They are passed to `browserify` because the `cache` and `packageCache` options are forwarded to [`module-deps`](https://github.com/substack/module-deps/blob/v4.0.2/index.js#L29-L31).

There is a comment from the author [here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1004#issuecomment-65747255):

> The caching options are forwarded along to module-deps: [`https://github.com/substack/module-deps/blob/master/index.js`](https://github.com/substack/module-deps/blob/master/index.js)

The contents of `cache` are not modified in `module-deps`, so its being passed is likely to be for performance reasons. However, the contents of `packageCache`  are modified, so it seems there is some interaction between `module-deps` and `watchify` via the shared `packageCache`.